# Sqlite query to fetch multiple records

Tags: sqlite

I have a sqlite DB with schema

column1 : Id(int)
column2 : Name(String)

I want to fetch records with id=x(say its "1") and name that matches any one of the values in array [x,y,z];
For eg,if the data in db is

1,a

1,b

2,a

2,b

1,x

1,y

1,z

The query should return

1,x

1,y

1,z

Can anyone help me with the query?.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at the SQL Syntax, or read any tutorials on SQL statements?

Comment: It would be 1,a 1,b 1,x 1,y 1,z surely?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen : Beginner for sqlite .In process of learning.

Comment: @andrewb : the output should be 1,x 1,y 1,z .

Comment: @andrewb : that is the requirement i want.The records name should match any one of the values in the array.

Comment: Make your post clearer. It reads that you want any rows with an id of 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for a basic [`SELECT` statement](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) with a [`WHERE` clause](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#whereclause)

```
SELECT
  id, name
FROM
  table
WHERE
  id = 1
  AND name IN ('x', 'y', 'z')
```

Comment: @Lasse You're right about the `IN` expression, couldn't remember whether or not SQLite supported it :)